# what is "-n" in the script?

Tags: perl

saw the script (see below) but could not find more info about "-n".

```
my $numeric =0;
my $input = shift;
if ($input eq "-n") {
    $numeric =1;
    $input = shift;
}
my $output = shift;
open INPUT, $input or die $!;
open OUTPUT, ">$output" or die $!;
my @file = <INPUT>;
if ($numeric) {
    @file = sort { $a <=> $b } @file;
} else {
   @file = sort @file;
}
print OUTPUT @file;
```

The text explaining the script says the following "If the first thing we see on the command line after our program's name is the string `-n`, then we are doing a numeric sort."
Google search does not seem to recognize most "non-alphanumeric" symbols, so `"-n"` search yields nothing. The only other place I saw `"-n"`is in learning perl, where it says the following "the converted `sed` script can operate either with or without `-n` option". Not even sure if this is the same `"-n"` as in the script. Any idea where I can find out more info about the `-n` (although it may simply means a numeric string ?? nothing else more)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `-n` used by this script is entirely unrelated to the `-n` flag used by `perl`. In other words, this:

```
perl -n script.pl
```

Is completely different from this:

```
perl script.pl -n
```

What you have is the second case. Take a look at the documentation for [`shift`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/shift.html):

> Shifts the first value of the array off and returns it, shortening the
>   array by 1 and moving everything down. If there are no elements in the
>   array, returns the undefined value. If ARRAY is omitted, shifts the @_
>   array within the lexical scope of subroutines and formats, and the
>   @ARGV array outside a subroutine and also within the lexical scopes
>   established by the eval STRING , BEGIN {} , INIT {} , CHECK {} ,
>   UNITCHECK {} , and END {} constructs.

That's a mouthfull, but what it's saying is that if we're not in a subroutine, and `shift` appears by itself, it's going to grab the first element of `@ARGV`. What's `@ARGV`? Let's look in [perlvar](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html), where all those weird variables are documented:

> The array @ARGV contains the command-line arguments intended for the
>   script.

Note that those are the arguments for the *script*, not for *perl*. So if somebody executes your script with `perl script.pl -n`, then we can expect `$ARGV[0]` to be the string `-n`.

Looking at your code now, it's obvious what's going on:

```
my $input = shift;
if ($input eq "-n") {
    $numeric =1;
    $input = shift;
}
```

They use `shift` without an argument and outside a subroutine to grab the first element of `@ARGV`. If that's `-n`, the variable `$numeric` is set to 1. That variable controls how the script behaves. (The script then goes on to get the names of the input and output files out of `@ARGV` as well.)

Answer (score 1):

Its a command line argument for this script itself. If the user invokes it with the name of the script followed by "-n" then that will tell the script how to behave.

Comment: still confused. How exactly should the script behave ?? i.e. with or without -n, what are the differences?

Comment: The "-n" is just something the creator of the script chose to signify that the input file should be numerically sorted instead of alphanumerically. It has nothing to do with command line arguments for any other program. The author could have just was well chosen "-i" or "--sort_numerically"

Comment: You're not going to find it on the Internet. The code comment you found explained it. It sorts the file. Suppose the script is called "sorter". Then if they write on the command line, "sorter infile outfile" it will read every line in infile, sort them alphabetically and then write the result to outfile. But if they write "sorter -n infile outfile" then it will read the lines and sort them as numbers instead of as strings.